# What am I doing wrong in converting char to int?

Tags: c

I am basically trying to convert a `char` vector to `int` values: in file **stage_03.txt** I have something like `10011 10101 10011 11001` etc. and the **stage_04.txt** file should look like `19 21 19` etc. This code works perfectly fine in Code::Blocks. However, the **stage_04.txt** file is totally messed up when I run the code in Linux terminal: `^R ^S ^D` etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
  char x[256];
  int aux[1000];
  int numar = 0;
  int z = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int l = 0;
  int ch;

  FILE *fin = fopen("stage_03.txt", "r");
  FILE *fout = fopen("stage_04.txt", "w");

  while ((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) {
    x[i++] = ch;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < l; i = i + 6) {
    numar = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
      numar = numar + (x[i + j] - '0') * pow(2, (4 - j));
    aux[z++] = numar;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < z - 1; i++) {
    fputc(aux[i], fout);
    fputc(' ', fout);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: `fputs` outputs a single character. You output a character with ASCII code 19, not two characters `'1'` and `'9'`. You are likely looking for `fprintf`, as in `fprintf(fout, "%d ", aux[i]);` (this also outputs the space after the number, for good measure).

Comment: it's not visible here, but x[] was declared as char x[256] and int aux[1000].

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yep, that solved the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: General tip: `pow` is meant for floating point, and it's not a great idea to use it for integer powers.  Especially powers of 2, which are much more efficient to compute with `1 << (4-j)`.

Comment: Please provide a code which i can compile without needing to complete missing definitions (f.e. variable `l` is not defined).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Please do not regard this as a "final" code. In final code one should divide the code into subprocedures and add error handling. I left this out for simplicity, here. The solution adds more flexibility concerning the separators and lengths of the numbers in the source file. 
It can easily deal with source files such as:

```
   0 1 00 01 10 11 000 001      010      011
100 101 110 111
0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101


0110 0111 1000 1001 1010          1011 1100 1101 1110
                    1111 10011 11001
```

You can see that fields do not need to have a fixed size of 6 character like in the original code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char sourceValues[256];
  int targetValues[1000];
  int number = 0;
  int numLength = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int charsToProcess = 0;
  int ch;
  const char *srcPtr = &sourceValues[0];
  int* targetPtr = &targetValues[0];

  FILE *fin = fopen("stage_03.txt", "r");
  FILE *fout = fopen("stage_04.txt", "w");

  // read source file and determine number of chars to be processed
  while ((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) {
    sourceValues[i++] = ch;
  }
  sourceValues[i] = '\0'; // terminate source data
  charsToProcess = i;
  srcPtr += strcspn(srcPtr, "01"); // eventually skip leading whitespace
  do {
    numLength = strcspn(srcPtr, " \t\n\r\v"); // determine runlength until next separator

    // Convert ASCII into binary form
    number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numLength; ++i)
    {
      number <<= 1; // Make room for next digit and propagate existing digits stepwise to their final place
      number += (*srcPtr++ == '1'); // Insert new digit at starting pos
    }

    *targetPtr++ = number; // Store converted number in binary representation in target array
    srcPtr += strcspn(srcPtr, "01"); // Skip whitespace. Set srcPtr to next numeric sequence
  } while (srcPtr < sourceValues + charsToProcess);

  for (const int *ptr = &targetValues[0]; ptr < targetPtr; ++ptr) {
    fprintf(fout, "%d ", *ptr);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output to the input given above:

```
0 1 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 19 25
```

Comment: The answer was already in the comments. However, considering the strict differentiation between answers and comments on this page an answer should be provided, though. Therefore i put it all together.